# How do I add data in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Well, I am creating a news feed website. Each user will be able to upload its own events. I am trying to create a section in my firebase database of the users, but I am not able of send variables to the arguments.

```
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(){
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      user.updateProfile({displayName: document.getElementById("name").value});
      var user_id = user.id;
      var user_email = user.email;
      var user_display_name = user.displayName;
      //Saving info in the data base.

      var database = firebase.database();
      database.ref('users/' + user_id).set({
          displayName: user_display_name,
          id: user_id,
          email: user_email
        });


      window.location = "index.html"
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
```

UPDATED VERSION:

```
window.onload = function(){

var createButton = document.getElementById("createButton");
var signin_button = document.getElementById("signin_button");

createButton.onclick = function(){

var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;



firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(result){ 
    console.log('result', result);
    if (result) {
      // User is signed in.
      result.updateProfile({displayName: document.getElementById("name").value});

      var user_info = {id: result.uid, email: result.email, display_name: result.displayName};
      console.log('user_info', user_info);
      // Storing user info into database.
      var database = firebase.database();

      console.log('user id', user_info.id);
      database.ref().child('usersss/' + user_info.id).push({
          displayName: user_info.display_name,
          id: user_info.id,
          email: user_info.email
       });

      window.location = "index.html"
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong.");
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
    alert('The password is too weak.');
  } else if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
    alert('The email is already in use.');
  } else if (errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
    alert('The email is not valid.');
  }else if (errorCode == 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
    alert('This operation is not allowed.');
  }else{
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  console.log(error);
})
```

}

```
signin_button.onclick = function(){
window.location = "login.html";
}
```

}

Comment: what error are you getting?  In your .then(function() - add the parameter (results like so:  `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(result) {

Comment: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property "user.undefined.id"

Comment: Take a look at the following article: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing exists at 'users/' + user_id you need to use 'push' instead of 'set'.  For example:

```
database.ref().child('/users/' + user_id).push({
//your code
```

try that.

Here's an action generator I use to log a user into firebase:

```
export var startLoginWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((result) => {
    //handle success
    console.log('worked', result);
  }).catch((error) => {
    //handle error
    console.log('error', error);
  });
}
```

In the above case, the 'result' object will have the user details.

Comment: It appears that I can't access the user_id... 

Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property "user.undefined.id"

Comment: I'm editing my original comment with an action generator (redux) I use to login with email and password.  Note the 'result' parameter - that object will contain the data you want to push to firebase.  I think that should help.  Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think I got it now.. I am gonna try it.

Comment: Great, let me know how it goes!

Comment: The part where I am stuck is that I can't use the variable inside the parameters of the part.

     database.ref().child('users/' + user_info.id).set({
        displayName: user_info.display_name,
        id: user_info.id,
        email: user_info.email
      });

Comment: I only need it to receive the user_info object.

Comment: The object inside the parameters should have whatever info you're looking for. Make your own object with it.  For example: `var obj = { displayName: result.displayName, id: result.id //etc etc` then use that to push to firebase.

Comment: I already created the object. What I dont understand is how to send it to the push so I can use it inside as you said.

Comment: How to send the object to firebase? Where exactly is it failing now. Are you able to see data saving inside firebase?

Comment: No!!! :(
There is something I am doing wrong but I dont know what it is. I have been stuck in here for a while.

Comment: You still don't have a parameter in your function. Change your first line to this: "firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(result){ "  then in the next line write console.log('result', result); and see what's contained in that object.  I'd also put a console.log statement after you declare the 'user' variable - see what's in there - console.log('user', user);

Comment: I see now. I did as you said and I saw that result and user are the same thing. So, I deleted the user stuff and replace it for result. The var user_info I declared it using the result attributes. That part fine. What I don't know is why firebase is not storing the data that I push in the database.

Comment: Good.  Did you initialize and configure firebase with you API key, authDoman, etc?

Comment: Yes, it is set up. And I have other parts of the project that uploads correctly to the database, but I don't know why this part doesn't.

Comment: I have two javascript files connected to my register.html: a "app.js" where I configured the database, and a "register.js" where I am running this part. In the original post I will upload the whole "register.js" file in the updated version section.

Comment: are you getting the same error?  I'm not sure, maybe try pushing without the user_id and see if that works. Example: database.ref().child('/usersss/').push({

Comment: @IronBoy how's it going?

Comment: Super!! I resolved that issue. Now I am encountering new ones in each step of the project. But I think that there is where the fun is. jejeje

Comment: That's how you know you're doing it right :) Good luck!